# 3D Camera Selection

Tags: ros, 3dcamera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a robot which will pick items from Point A and deliver it to Point B.
For this purpose I planned to use a 3D camera and plan the strategy as follows.

1. Selection of 3D camera [Stereo, TOF or Structured light, Please suggest which one will be the suitable solution?]
2. Generation of Dense 3D point cloud data, [ By fusion of Laser scanner data and the camera data]
3. Filter and feature extraction from data , Obstacle avoidance , path planning from Point A to Point B.

If there is any tutorial available which matches with my goals it would be great.
Which steps are missing in my strategy ?

Thankyou in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232270/3d-camera-selection/) by [Jackie_16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26639/jackie_16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-04-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-04-19**:
I'd recommend editing your question to provide a more descriptive title. People aren't likely to click on a question with a generic title.

**Comment by [Jackie_16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26639/jackie_16/) on 2016-04-19**:
ok thanks :)

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-04-19**:
How much money do you want to spend?

**Comment by [Jackie_16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26639/jackie_16/) on 2016-04-19**:
@Nengelhard  Lets say for camera part, 300-400$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) stack (navstack) would be a good place to start. The navstack provides functionality for path planning, obstacle avoidance, localization, mapping, etc. The navstack is designed to run with a variety of sensors. People have used depth cameras (such as a Kinect) and laser scanners of all varieties successfully with the navstack.

If you are looking to create your own solution, then you are definitely on the right track. Be aware that your step 3 will take quite a lot of effort to get everything working well on a real robot. My advice would be to start with an already-available solution (e.g. the navstack), and then figure out the parts of that solution that you aren't happy with or the parts that you're interested in concentrating your efforts on. Then write your implementations to be compatible with the solution you started with.

The navstack has many great tutorials to get you started.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jackie_16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26639/jackie_16/) on 2016-04-19**:
Great! I understand. Thank you so much.